# Accept new row in DataGridView without manually changing its value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a *`databound`* `DataGridView`.
To insert a new row I handle `DefaultValuesNeeded`.

The new row is displayed with my assigned values. Up to here it works fine.

At this time the row is not yet attached to the underlying `DataTable`. *That's OK*.

The only way to accept the new row is to set any cell in edit mode, change
the value and close the editor.
Now the new row gets added to the `DataTable`.

My problem is that I want to add the row with minimal user input.
If the user decides that the values are fine he/she should be able to confirm
without changing some cell values (and setting them back to the original value)

Is there a way to achieve this, e.g. by pressing *enter*, trap the command and force
the `DataGridView` to do the same as if a cell value changed?

I have already tried to change the values in `dgv_KeyDown()` without success.
Any suggestions?

```
private void dgv_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (dgv.CurrentCell != null && dgv.CurrentCell.OwningRow.DataBoundItem == null)
        {
            //ToDo: Accept the new row

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I have to set the cell state dirty and enter edit mode. Otherwise the internal state will get corrupted when selecting another row

```
private void dgv_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (dgv.CurrentCell != null && dgv.CurrentCell.OwningRow.DataBoundItem == null)
        {
            dgv.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            dgv.BeginEdit(true);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, you can using the [CellValidating Even](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)t and [RowValidating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx) to achieve this task.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty) //or IsCurrentRowDirty
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("You're about to change the value. Do you want to continue?\n\nPress ESC to cancel change.",
                                    "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is not quite what I intended to do. I want to add the not jet attached row to my datasource and not prevent to change a value.